# Parse Input Attribute Name into Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, parsing, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse information from checked checkboxes into divs. I currently have a jquery script parsing the value attribute and adding them together to get a total like this:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.option').click(function(){                  
        var total = 0;

        $('.option:checked').each(function(){
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
        });         
        $('#total').html('$'+ total);           
    });
});
</script>
```

The second part I'm trying to do is give a line item summary of the checkboxes checked, so I tried using the 'name' attribute for the line item description. However, I can't get the text out of the name element. I've tried several ways but no success. Here is an example using the same format as the value element.

```
 <script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.option').click(function(){                  
         $('.option:checked').each(function(){
        var selection = $(this).attr('name');
         });
    $('#summary').html(selection);
     });
});
</script>
```

Here is my html:

```
 <div id="fragment-1">
     <ul class="tanks">
         <li><img src="tankthumb.jpg" alt="560 Gallon Tank"/><br /><input type="checkbox" class="option" name="560 Gallon Tank" value="500"/> 560 Gallon Tank</li>
         <li><img src="2000tank.jpg" alt="1000 Gallon Tank"/><br /><input type="checkbox" class="option" name="1000 Gallon Tank" value="800"/>1000 Gallon Tank</li>
         <li><img src="2000tank.jpg" alt="2000 Gallon Tank"/><br /><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="1600"/>2000 Gallon Tank</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="summary">

</div>
<div id="total" style="border-top:1px solid; margin-top:450px;">
$0
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```js
$('.option:checked').each(function () {
    var selection = $(this).attr('name');
});
$('#summary').html(selection);
```

where `var selection` is local to the function given to `each`. This way `selection` is not available outside, in order to set the `#summary` html.

If you want to collect all `name` attribute strings, you must do something like

```js
var selection = '';
$('.option:checked').each(function () {
    selection += $(this).attr('name') + '<br>';
});
$('#summary').html(selection);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GzazW/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `selection` is defined within the scope of the `$('.option:checked').each` function.
You need to define that variable outside of the scope, like this:

```
    $('.option').click(function(){   
         var selection = "";
         $('.option:checked').each(function(){          
              selection = $(this).attr('name');          
         });

         $('#summary').html(selection);
    });
```